# Angular momentum and Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation, quantum-states

I'm studying stationary states and their orbital angular momentum in 3D Schrodinger equation. I have tried to understand by myself the situation but I get lost. I think it might be useful to know which cases are possible before starting the derivation by myself, so can you tell me:

> Which of the following three situations are possible?

1. A stationary state in a **central field** that has a non **determined modulus** of the orbital angular-momentum.
2. A stationary state in a **non-central field** that has a **non determined modulus** of the orbital angular-momentum.
3. A stationary state in a **non-central field** has a **determined modulus** of the orbital angular-momentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a central force is spherically symmetric. From Noether's theorem, this implies that angular momentum is conserved. Equivalently, the angular momentum operator commutes with the Hamiltonian. This implies that $L^2$ and $H$ have simultaneous eigenvectors, so there are stationary states (i.e. eigenvectors of $H$) which have definite angular momentum (i.e. eigenvectors of $L^2$). Let's see what this argument implies about each of the three cases:

1. $L^2$ and $H$ must share some eigenstates. However, there's no guarantee that they share all eigenstates. When $H$ has repeated eigenvalues, there might exist eigenstates of $H$ which are not also eigenstates of $L^2$, so this is possible.
2. This is also possible, for more or less the same reason as 1.
3. Two operators can share one eigenstate without sharing a complete basis of eigenstates, so this is possible.